# Deactivate Kafka message sending and receiving for testing in Spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I want to do some integration testing in a spring boot project, where kafka is used.

For these tests I don't want any messages to be sent or received from kafka. Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

[Kafka test containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/) help me to do integration tests with kafka
. May be it'll help you.